# instal ubuntu 12.04 LTS and now boot from HDD?

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my computer and have now booted from HDD. Then I got a  purple page saying "GNU GRUB VERSION 1.99-21ubuntu3,9" and I have the following options:

- Ubuntu, with linux 3.5.0-23-generic,
- Ubuntu, with linux 3.5.0-23-generic (recovery mode)
- previous linux version
- memory test(memtest 86+)
- memory test(memtest 86+, serial console 1152000)

Which one is the right to boot my newly installed Ubuntu system?

Comment: Select one option? Just kidding... you need to select the first option to boot to your newly installed system. The second option is used to recover your system after some problem and the two other to test your memory for hardware problems.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/263217/what-to-do-on-ubuntu-grub-screen

Answer (score 1):

The first option is the actuall Ubuntu 12.04. The others are just to check your computer.