# What to do on Ubuntu GRUB screen?

Tags: installation, boot

Installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and now boot from HDD. Now come that purple page "GNU GRUB VERSION 1.99-21ubuntu3.9" and the options are:

1. Ubuntu, with linux 3.5.0-23-generic
2. Ubuntu, with linux 3.5.0-23-generic (recovery mode)
3. Previous linux version
4. memory test(memtest 86+)
5. memory test(memtest 86+, serial console 1152000)

So can someone told me what to do?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the first option at the top. That will boot you to Ubuntu.

Comment: really thankz and sorry for my english!!!!thankz

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind even using good formatting is sufficient, as Erick Carvalho did in their edit.  Also, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted, if it allows you to (you may need to wait a bit)